# Using QtQuick Loader vs the property visible

Tags: qt, qml

Let's say I have a general implementation to represent a screen. The screen has a footer. The footer can have the following content:

- empty or
- one button on the left or
- one button on the right or
- one button on the left and one button on the right

I have at least 20 instances of this screen implementation within my application. I was wondering if it is better to load the buttons with a QML Loader component only if they are used within the given screen or it doesn't make that big of a difference to have the buttons always there just turn on/off their visibility?

Sidenote: each screen knows upfront how many buttons will it need if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't make a lot of difference in most cases. The trade-back is CPU time vs RAM usage, hiding will save CPU time but use more memory, creating and destroying will save memory but add CPU load.

It would only begin to matter if the components are heavy and complex, which means that they will be slow to create, and use a lot of memory, in that case you have to decide based on which of the two you prefer to avoid.

Unless you already have established to have a problem with how your app performs, don't bother with premature optimizations.